# WPF TextBox Spellcheck not working in Windows Embedded

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded

I have a WPF .Net project in which I have a TextBox with SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true".  It is compiled for .Net 4 and works (misspelled words underlined in red) on a standard installed of Windows.  I have tried it on full versions of Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10 all without any issues.  All good so far....

However, the problem I have is that the application needs to run on Windows 8 Embedded and it currently isn't working.  This is an in-house build of Embedded that has been streamlined for a specific purpose.  It does have all versions of .Net installed up to and including 4.5.2. I have some scope for asking for additional components to be added, but I am trying to find out what component(s) is missing.

The symptom of the issue is that spell checking just isn't happening (i.e. no red underlining of misspelled words).  Other than this, the text box works as expected.

I have tried (for testing purposes) just creating a text box in code wrapped in a try catch and passing it a misspelled word which works on full Windows, but not on Embedded and no errors are thrown.  I have checked the Windows event logs and nothing is reported.

I have tried running dependency walker and whilst there where approx five dll's supposedly missing, getting these dll's from my development PC and putting them onto the Embedded windows along side the application made no difference.

Looking at forums, I get the impression that the dictionary is within the .Net framework? so am assuming it is not just that it can't find the dictionary.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using the `IsEnabled` properly instead of the `setIsEnabled`. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.setisenabled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I've checked and both IsEnabled and SetIsEnabled are both valid depending on what your path is:

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
                SpellCheck.SetIsEnabled(tb, true);

Comment: OK, getting used to StackOverflow, so my last comment isn't formatted well.  In the code example, I meant either/or is acceptable.  As it goes, I enabled the spell check in the XAML for the text box: <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" FontSize="18" Uid="txtBox">